# List comprehension not working?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a for loop like this:

```
 for k in file1:
            shared_username = User.objects.filter(id__in= Share.objects.filter(users_id = log_id, files__file_name=k).values_list('shared_user_id', flat=True))
```

## List comprehension

```
shared_username = [User.objects.filter(id__in= Share.objects.filter(users_id = log_id, files__file_name=k).values_list('shared_user_id', flat=True)) for k in file1]
```

But I am getting empty entries.

Comment: You are setting the variable `shared_username` inside the brackets.

Comment: You have said multiple times "Sorry I posted my question incorrectly. That's not what I am doing. " Just delete this question and make a new one, take time to format it and preview it before you post, and review the [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use equality operator inside such construction. Maybe try:

```
a_list = [User.objects.filter(id__in= Share.objects.filter(users_id = log_id, files__file_name=k).values_list('shared_user_id', flat=True)) for k in file1]
```

Comment: Sorry I posted my question incorrectly. That's not what I am doing.